# Is there a different between one hot encoding and labelling categorical as scalar value and then normalise the batch?

Tags: machine-learning, keras

Let's say I have `label = ['Male', 'Female', 'Undefined']`.
Is there a difference if I label it as:

```
[[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]
```

compare to labeling it as

`[0, 1, 2]` and then normalize the data later?

On the topic of this, what if I have another feature age, which of course only has the length of 1. How would I input Age and Gender in the case I choose one hot encoding, since the length of Gender now becomes 3? I'm using Keras.

Answer (score 1):

The second option is wrong. If you label `Male`, `Female`, `Undefined` as `[0, 1, 2]` you are treating categories as numbers. That is not correct. The Network in this way would learn something such as `Undefined > Female`, which doesn't make sense.

You need **one hot encoding** to treat those variables: they are not a numerical values that you can put on a scale.

About the `Age` question: if that's a numerical variable (expressed in years, I guess?) then you can feed it directly into the Neural Network without problems.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. But what I meant was to input data with shape (1,) and shape (3,) together.

Comment: I see. You need one input for each variable - and each one hot encoded category counts as one. So, if you input variables:  `[Male, Female, Undefined, Age]` then your `input_shape` will be `= (None, 4)`. Please let me know if it's what you need.